# PopupWindow.getContentView().getLayoutParams() returns a different class in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android

I am having a code such as below.

```
....
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(someView);
final WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) popupWindow.getContentView().getLayoutParams();
....
```

The problem popupWindow.getContentView().getLayoutParams is returning differnt classes as below because of which my typecast is failing

Before Marshamallow : android.View.WindowManager.LayoutParams

For Marshmallow : android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutParams

Has anyone faced the issue before or any resolutions please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right. M wraps everything inside a FrameLayout called `mDecorView`. If you dig into the PopupWindow source you will find something like `createDecorView(View contentView)`. The main purpose of `mDecorView` is to handle event dispatch and content transitions, which are new to M.

To get a hold of your contentView try:

`View container = (View) popupWindow.getContentView().getParent();
container.getLayoutParams();`

Keep in mind that if your contentView's background is not null it will be nested twice. This would mean: `(View) popupWindow.getContentView().getParent().getParent();`

Comment: But I can't seem to find getLayourParams() in getParent() method?

Comment: I am unable to get it... getContentView().getParent() returns a ViewParent. I can't see a way that this can be typecasted to View as you have mentioned. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, taking it as (View) worked for me in the past. I have no M to test on currently, will look into it when i get to it.

Comment: It works fine with typecast to View. This resolves my issue. Thanks!!

Comment: View container = (View) popUp.getContentView().getRootView();

Use this. Works on pre and post Android M (tested on Jelly bean and Marshmallow).

Comment: I've seen a crash on Android 5.1.1 where getContentView().getParent() returned ViewRootImpl and not View or ViewGroup. This caused a crash when I tried to cast this to View.
@Sanju - using getRootView() will get the top most view of the popup-window, but we try to get to the view that holds the popup - its parent view...